# setState changes constructor type

Tags: reactjs

I found that, when a class instance is set through `setState`, it loses its constructor and become a `plain object`. I see in the document `setState` merges the value with current state and may be not possible to handle complex type. So, should the state always be plain builtin type?

http://jsfiddle.net/58c8e7e3/1/

===== code ===

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

//===============  transpiled through babeljs.io ======//
function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

var Data = (function () {
    function Data() {
        _classCallCheck(this, Data);
    }

    Data.prototype.isLoading = function isLoading() {
        return this.__state == 2;
    };

    return Data;
})();

//============

var Hello = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return new Data();
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
      State: <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state)} proto: {this.state.constructor.name} </pre>
      <button onClick={this.setXsimple}>setState</button>
      </div>
    );
  },

  setXsimple: function() {
    this.setState(new Data());
  }
});

React.renderComponent(<Hello name="World" />, document.body);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `this.state` should be a plain JavaScript object. You can, however, have complex types as the *values* of that object:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

//===============  transpiled through babeljs.io ======//
function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

var Data = (function () {
    function Data() {
        _classCallCheck(this, Data);
    }

    Data.prototype.isLoading = function isLoading() {
        return this.__state == 2;
    };

    return Data;
})();

//============

var Hello = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { data: new Data() };
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
      State: <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state)} proto: {this.state.data.constructor.name} </pre>
      <button onClick={this.setXsimple}>setState</button>
      </div>
    );
  },

  setXsimple: function() {
    this.setState({ data: new Data() });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you think it is better to use plain objects or arrays if the data object is further passed as props to a child component. I am wondering whether using plain object makes it efficient to do change detection.

Comment: Props can be anything. Change detection is easiest with immutable values as you can simply do reference equality.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate):

> The first argument can be an object (containing zero or more keys to
>   update) or a function (of state and props) that returns an object
>   containing keys to update.

I assume they are referring to plain objects here, not classes or arrays f. ex.